# how to detect triple click on website on ios device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, click

I have to show and hide a div on triple click on body of my website in mobile devices
the below code that I wrote in JavaScript is work fine in android devices but it doesn't work in IOS.
so would you please help me to resolve it?

the code is :

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();
    if (evt.detail === 3) {
      document.getElementById('mmu').style.height = '100px';
    }

    if (evt.detail === 1) {
      document.getElementById('mmu').style.height = '0px';
    }

  });

}
```

```css
#mmu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="mmu"></div>
```

Comment: what does `evt.detail` returning?

Comment: @AswinKumar It work fine in desktop and android devices. evt.detail return count of user click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, the `click` event doesn't fire normally. Instead you will need monitor touch events such as [`touchend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchend_event) to check how many taps are made.

For example you might try to check if the taps are made within a sufficient timeout window like so

```js
TOUCH_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS = 500
touch_count = 0
window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('touchend', function (evt) {
        touch_count += 1

        setTimeout(function () {
            touch_count = 0
        }, TOUCH_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);

        if (touch_count === 3) {
            document.getElementById('mmu').style.height = '100px';
        }

        if (touch_count === 1) {
            document.getElementById('mmu').style.height = '0px';
        }

        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Depending on what your requirements are you may also need to account for `touchend` and `click` events firing from the same action.